Comedy/Sci-Fi movie about one of the last men on Earth living in a museum/zoo on display for humanoid robots
And I'm back with another story ident

Pretty sure it's a movie
No idea when I watched it
I only remember one scene, and it's a guy trapped in a room (bad artist's rendition below)
Guy collects toys from cereal boxes which he collects and displays on shelves.
He's almost the last guy on earth, the "people" observing him are humanoid robots. he can also see them and mostly ignores them.
I think a female is brought in to accompany him and they run away together and it ends with like a scene of the outdoors or smth
Guy is content with being stuck on display like a zoo animal for most of the movie, he just watches TV, eats and sleeps.
MC is a white man


I have just recently seen this movie. He is living in as an exhibit in a Museum/Zoo. Robots are the "Customers" coming to view him. Its a Comedy. If I remember correctly he pretty much only eats cereal and has collected hundreds(Thousands?) of toys from the cereal boxes, which he arranges on shelves. I believe he starts frequently hiding in the bathroom to jerk off, and they bring a woman hoping to observe  mating practices. Which they don't want to do publicly and drives them to want to escape.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PeopleZoo

A US made move, the MC was an Adam Sandler/Seth Rogen type of comedy actor. I think he was a "wild human" until he was captured and put in the museum, where he decided this is not so bad, and was content to live there. He was pretty much a slob.

@Valorum I already looked there without finding anything.

https://tropedia.fandom.com/wiki/People_Zoo#Live_Action_TV

The scenario of a guy on show in a zoo reminds me of a scene in Slaughterhouse 5 by Kurt Vonnegut. There is a film but I've never seen it. Does anyone know if this matches?

@skyjack, same scenario, but not a match.

oh well...  so it goes...

Heigh-ho.  If I live, I'm going to come back and delete this comment.

Sounds like "In Captivity", saw this in a movie recap a while ago.



https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1773494/
It is  a 2011 short film:

As the only living part of a futuristic museum exhibit meant to replicate the "ideal" human existence, Jim has everything a man could wish for. With complimentary microwave dinners, unlimited thirst-quenching soda, and over five television channels to choose from, who could ask for anything more? But when his cyborg caretakers decide to introduce a female into the exhibit, his world changes forever. As he tries to relate to Caz, a living, breathing woman, Jim discovers that maybe his sheltered life isn't all it's cracked up to be. After a few chaotic days together, they decide that Caz is going to leave on her own. After she escapes, a lonely Jim is forced to decide whether he has the courage to follow her and face the outside world.

caps shows toy collection, viewing window with cyborgs, protaganist eating cereal:


Did not realize it was only a short film and not a full length movie, but yes this is exactly what I remember, just need the OP to confirm. ;)

It is strange to see a recap more than half the length of the film
